How can I use @recogito/annotorious in Next.js?
I tried to use @recogito/annotorious in Next.js.
I have already used that package in React app and it worked.
I am migrating the React app to Next.js, however, I got the error with Annotorious.
How can I fix this?
Here is what I have done.
const Annotorious = dynamic(() => import("@recogito/annotorious"), { ssr: false, });

const ImageAnnotator = ({ imgUrl, arrayOfAnnotations, setArrayOfAnnotations }) => {

    const imgEl = useRef();

    const [anno, setAnno] = useState();

    const [tool, setTool] = useState('rect');

    useEffect(() => {
        let annotorious = null;

        if (imgEl.current) {
            const annotorious = new Annotorious({
                image: imgEl.current
            });

            annotorious.on('createAnnotation', annotation => {
                console.log('annotations', arrayOfAnnotations);
            });

            annotorious.on('updateAnnotation', (annotation, previous) => {
                console.log('updated', annotation, previous);

            });

            annotorious.on('deleteAnnotation', annotation => {
                console.log('deleted', annotation);
            });
            annotorious.on('selectAnnotation', function (a, shape) {
                console.log('selected');
            });
        }

        setAnno(annotorious);

        return () => annotorious.destroy();
    }, [arrayOfAnnotations]);

But this code shows the error
annotorious.on is not a function
This component worked in React.

This does look ok as far as I can tell... can you confirm (e.g. via console logs) that none of the code is actually executed on the server in SSR? Is the image element (imgEl.current) defined when you create the new Annotorious instance? If you log out the annotorious instance right after you created it, what does the log show?
